# red arrow symbol which roles back lyx files to an older version

Tags: lyx, revision-control, trackchanges

Does anyone know exactly what these red arrows roll back mean,

That is, the 8 red arrows on the RHS of the 7 or 8 repeated lines in pasted picture/screen shot below of my lyx document mean?

They appear to be related with accidentally pasting of  copies of older parts of the documents into sections(particular when it includes maths codes) which often messes up the entire section

Moreover, and sometimes roll back the Lyx document to an older version.

[image]

Comment: Off-Topic: Please always use [tag `lyx`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lyx) if you have a LyX question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red arrows mean line breaks. They use the LaTeX `\\`. They are useful when you want to have a line break but not start a new paragraph. You can insert them with either Ctrl + Enter or Insert > Formatting > Ragged Line Break

Comment: indcidentally, i am not very experienced in lyx. What does the greyed out formatting on your symbol \\ denote. Is this some kind of special editing mode, within lyx or mini-marddowned for formatting mode. Is seems that most of the commands can be manually typed in, more easily into some kind of greyed out editor format of the file

Comment: is this within the context of ctrl m or maths mode. Generally i used to be able press enter to go to the next line. I presume this should not done within lyx. And that line breaks and paragraphs should be offiically or explicitely inserts. Does it otherwise potentially mess up the document?

Comment: I presume there is no way to ensure that line breaking is automatic, both outside context of maths mode and within it, so it that code does not overflow the margins

Comment: the greyed out just signifies that it's code. If you press enter, that will take start a new paragraph. I highly recommend that you read the LyX help files. Start them in the order they are listed. They are a little dry, but if you spend some time on them now, they will give you a better understanding of things.

Comment: thanks for this. I apologize if these questions seem a bit trivial.

Comment: @scottkostyWhat,I,mean,is,the,mode,or,layour.that,.is.ofthis,form:   that is where you add commands like this   : [documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[left=.45in,right=.45in,top=.6in,bottom=.6in,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow,textcomp}]




\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Tech&\multicolumn{4}{c}{Single hom}& \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Excepted Case}\\ \cline{2-8}
 &\\ ]
   &&&&&&&\\ ]

   &&&&&&&\\ 
   &&&&&&&\\ 
   &&&&&&&\\        
   &&&&&&&\\ \hline


\end{tabular}

 \end{document}

Comment: Incidentally how do i grey something out exactly within lyx and so forth

Comment: not sure what you mean by grey out in LyX. Maybe give a new question? Are you referring to the \\ in my question? If so, that is just markup when writing a comment. You put code in-between backticks.

Comment: dear scott I will give you an example

Comment: if you look at this question and scroll down to where it refers to source code, there is a  screen shot of a big grey block of lyx code where it appears you can code in all of the preambles etc  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378701/is-there-a-way-to-fix-the-limitation-of-cleveref-package-regarding-citation-of-sthe

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I was wondering how I get my Lyx document into that format. Is there a mark down button within Lyx itself, or is only done within documents using ert. Do you have to begin the lyx document in that format from the state, if you want to change it to the formate

Comment: you can only export from LyX to LaTeX (see the file menu). I really think it would be worth your time to read the Help files. They have a lot of good information.

Comment: i mean this (Insert > ERT box) through ctrl T. Indeed I think we should dicuss in chat. Isee that some or most people have their entire document in that format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61916/discussion-between-william-balthes-and-scottkosty).

Comment: I am not so much talking about \\ i am talking about hte grey box font itself  or how does one get ones own lyx document into that format

Comment: If you want to enter code directly, yes the ERT is the way to go. But as mentioned in another question you might be interested in using LaTeX directly instead of using LyX.