# Is there a way to fix the limitation of cleveref package regarding citation of subfloats?

Tags: tables, floats, cross-referencing, subfloats, cleveref

When referencing floats using `\cref` commands, they may sometimes yield an incorrect typesetting. That's especially true when subfloats are included.

An example is when we have float 1 with two subfloats; the range `1a and 2 to 5` will be mistaken as though it is from `1a to 5`. Also, if both `1a` and `1b` are ncluded in the source code referencing, it is supposed to mention all of subfloats included in the source code, not only one of them (see point 2). Typeset output is shown below:

[image]

This output is generated using the following source code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{paralist}



\begin{document}


    \begin{subfigures}

        % Subfigure 1
        \begin{figure}[H]

            \centering
            \fbox{\Huge Figure 1a}


            \caption{Caption 1}
            \label{fig1a}

        \end{figure}


        % Subfigure 2
        \begin{figure}[H]

            \centering
            \fbox{\Huge Figure 1b}


            \caption{Caption 1b}
            \label{fig1b}

        \end{figure}


    \end{subfigures}


    % Figure 2
    \begin{figure}[H]

        \centering
        \fbox{\Huge Figure 2}


        \caption{Caption 2}
        \label{fig2}

    \end{figure}


    % Figure 3
    \begin{figure}[H]

        \centering
        \fbox{\Huge Figure 3}


        \caption{Caption 3}
        \label{fig3}

    \end{figure}


    % Figure 4
    \begin{figure}[H]

        \centering
        \fbox{\Huge Figure 4}


        \caption{Caption 4}
        \label{fig4}

    \end{figure}


    % Figure 5
    \begin{figure}[H]

        \centering
        \fbox{\Huge Figure 5}


        \caption{Caption 5}
        \label{fig5}

    \end{figure}


    % Figure 6
    \begin{figure}[H]

        \centering
        \fbox{\Huge Figure 6}


        \caption{Caption 6}
        \label{fig6}

    \end{figure}



    \newpage
    Figures are correctly cited for different citation formats such as:

    \begin{enumerate}

        \item Multiple: \textbf{\cref{fig5,,fig3,,fig4,,fig2}}
        \item Range: \textbf{\cref{fig5,fig3,fig4}}
        \item Multiple and range: \textbf{\cref{fig2,fig4,fig3,fig6}}

    \end{enumerate}


    \vspace{5mm}
    But once subfigures are included, some citations formats do not work:

    \begin{enumerate}

    \item Multiple (works): \textbf{\cref{fig3,,fig4,,fig2,,fig1a}}
    \item Range: \textbf{\cref{fig1a,fig1b,fig5,fig3,fig4}} (the output should be \textbf{figs. 1a to 1b and 3 to 5})
    \item Multiple and range: \textbf{\cref{fig1a,fig2,fig4,fig3,fig6}} (the output should be \textbf{figs. 1a, 2 to 4 and 6})

    \end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

I already have a solution that mitigates the problem, but not with the same expected output above.

Comment: @cfr I was working on the answer when you posted the comment.

Comment: The best thing to do in such cases is to state that you are going to post a partial/unsatisfactory solution as an initial answer later. Or to include it in your question, if it really doesn't solve the problem. (Once a question has an answer, people are obviously that much less inclined to view it to see if they can help.)

Comment: Is `paralist` necessary? Is `float`? Can you reproduce with just `subfloat` and `cleveref`?

Comment: `float` allows for deciding the figures locations using `[H]` after `\begin{figure}`. `paralist` is used to provide a list of cases on how the typeset referencing output looks like.

Comment: Example produces same output with neither, though. You aren't using `paralist` at all. For `cleveref`, see page 26 of the manual: 'Cleveref doesn’t know about the subfloat package, so you have to revert
to using `\ref` for cross-references to sub-figures. (Might be fixed in a future
version.)'

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
We can define new float type (`subfig`) for `cleveref`

```
\crefformat{subfig}{fig. #1}
\crefrangeformat{subfig}{figs. #1 to #2}
\crefmultiformat{subfig}{figs. #1}{ and #1}{, #1}{ and #1}
\crefrangemultiformat{subfig}{figs. #1 to #2}{}{}{}
```

Then in the preamble we define a new command:

```
\newcommand{\labelsf}[1]{ \label[subfig]{#1} } % a new command for labeling subfigures
```

`labelsf` can now be used to label subfigures.

A full source code is shown below:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{paralist}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{subfig}{fig. #1}
\crefrangeformat{subfig}{figs. #1 to #2}
\crefmultiformat{subfig}{figs. #1}{ and #1}{, #1}{ and #1}
\crefrangemultiformat{subfig}{figs. #1 to #2}{}{}{}
\newcommand{\labelsf}[1]{ \label[subfig]{#1} } % a new command for labeling subfigures

\begin{document}


    \begin{subfigures}

        % Subfigure 1
        \begin{figure}[H]

            \centering
            \fbox{\Huge Figure 1a}


            \caption{Caption 1}
            \labelsf{fig1a}

        \end{figure}


        % Subfigure 2
        \begin{figure}[H]

            \centering
            \fbox{\Huge Figure 1b}


            \caption{Caption 1b}
            \labelsf{fig1b}

        \end{figure}


    \end{subfigures}


    % Figure 2
    \begin{figure}[H]

        \centering
        \fbox{\Huge Figure 2}


        \caption{Caption 2}
        \label{fig2}

    \end{figure}


    % Figure 3
    \begin{figure}[H]

        \centering
        \fbox{\Huge Figure 3}


        \caption{Caption 3}
        \label{fig3}

    \end{figure}


    % Figure 4
    \begin{figure}[H]

        \centering
        \fbox{\Huge Figure 4}


        \caption{Caption 4}
        \label{fig4}

    \end{figure}


    % Figure 5
    \begin{figure}[H]

        \centering
        \fbox{\Huge Figure 5}


        \caption{Caption 5}
        \label{fig5}

    \end{figure}


    % Figure 6
    \begin{figure}[H]

        \centering
        \fbox{\Huge Figure 6}


        \caption{Caption 6}
        \label{fig6}

    \end{figure}



    \newpage
    Figures are correctly cited for different citation formats such as:

    \begin{enumerate}

        \item Multiple: \textbf{\cref{fig5,,fig3,,fig4,,fig2}}
        \item Range: \textbf{\cref{fig5,fig3,fig4}}
        \item Multiple and range: \textbf{\cref{fig2,fig4,fig3,fig6}}

    \end{enumerate}


    \vspace{5mm}
    But once subfigures are included, some citations formats do not work:

    \begin{enumerate}

    \item Multiple (works): \textbf{\cref{fig3,,fig4,,fig2,,fig1a}}
    \item Range: \textbf{\cref{fig1a,fig1b,fig5,fig3,fig4}} (the output should be \textbf{figs. 1a to 1b and 3 to 5})
    \item Multiple and range: \textbf{\cref{fig1a,fig2,fig4,fig3,fig6}} (the output should be \textbf{figs. 1a, 2 to 4 and 6})

    \end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

`cref` now will reference subfigures correctly, but the disadvantage of this solution are:

- we cannot find the usages of floats by double-clicking on their
  labels and we also cannot find the float source code by clicking on
  its label
- the name of the float can sometimes be repeated twice, which is
  redundant

Comment: You won't get hyperlinks without `hyperref` anyway, if that's what you mean. Are you talking about features of your editor? That has nothing to do with TeX itself. You can always use a different editor.

Comment: Yes, my editor is not able to find usages if I customized the `\label`command