# *mark up editor mode*

Tags: macros, lyx, lyx-layouts, mathspec

How do i find the command to view lyx in the **mark up editor mode**, where on can add command to insert new packages layouts, margin spaces, centering etc, and the document class such as .  For example

See this question as an example. **[Is there a way to fix the limitation of cleveref package regarding citation of subfloats?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378701/is-there-a-way-to-fix-the-limitation-of-cleveref-package-regarding-citation-of-sthe)**

It has not so much to with that particular question, this is just an example of what I am asking about. If you look at that question and you and scroll down to the picture of a 'screen shot of a big greyed section of a  lyx document', its listed as being created by source code.

THis is what I am asking about. How do do this or view my lyx document in that form. Greyed out **add command, use package form.**?

```
`\sloppy
```

`use[package`]..

I will give a better example soon`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Lyx document you can insert a Latex code in the LaTeX preamble in <kbd>Document</kbd> > <kbd>Settings ...</kbd> > <kbd>LaTeX preamble</kbd> and in the body of the document  making a ERT  (Evil Red Text) aka TeX Code with <kbd>Insert</kbd> > <kbd>TeX Code</kbd> or with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

In both cases, be sure that the inserted code do not break the LateX syntax, checking the Source Pane with <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Source Pane</kbd>  (this is NOT a mark up editor mode, you **cannot edit the LaTeX code generated (exported) by LyX directly**, only that what you insert as explained above).

In special, do not try to insert packages in the LateX preamble that are already loaded by lyx automatically. If needed, you should change this packages through the other panels of the Documents Settings menu.